# Disable text fit in div when width is decreased

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I try to decrease the width of a div (using jquery .animate() function) the text that is inside that div is trying to fit and the words break-down . How can I avoid that ?

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
    $("#myDiv").animate({"width":"0px"}, 400);
});
```

I create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/George02/Ka8MJ/) to illustrate what I want to avoid .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this css:

```
#myDiv{
  overflow: hidden;
}
#myDiv p{
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: what about using #myDiv p {width:100%;} can I get this works ?

Comment: You could probably set the width at runtime with jQuery: `$("#myDiv p").css({width: $("#myDiv").width()})` then you can remove the width line in the css

Answer (score 1):

Create another div that is wrapped by #myDiv, give this div a fixed width, and set `overflow:hidden` on #mydiv.

You may not need to set the overflow hidden, depending on how you want the final thing to look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the `<p>` a specific width, otherwise it resizes to the size of the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<body>
<div id="myDiv" style="width:200px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
    <p style="position:absolute;width:200px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;margin:0;padding:0">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
</div>
<button id="btn">Click this</button>
</body>
```

Script

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
    $("#myDiv").animate({"width":"0px"}, 400);
});
```

I have updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ka8MJ/12/